# Android: Disconnection of Bluetooth for Samsung S6 (Android Version: Lollipop)

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have developed an android application on Samsung S6 mobile (Android Version:- Lollipop).
The application reads data on Bluetooth port and displays on screen.

However, the Bluetooth connection is lost after sometime.
After that, the Bluetooth gets connected-disconnected continuously.

The connection log is:-

**03-05 15:34:57.071: E/bt-btm(6152): Reset sec_bd_name and name flag. 
(BR/EDR link)**

**03-05 15:34:57.071: E/bt-btm(6152): btm_sec_disconnected - Clearing Pending flag**

**invalid rfc slot id: 91**

**03-05 16:37:42.490: W/bt-btif(6113): dm_pm_timer expires**

**03-05 16:37:42.490: W/bt-btif(6113): dm_pm_timer expires 0**

**03-05 16:37:42.490: W/bt-btif(6113): proc dm_pm_timer expires**

When i restart the mobile, everything work fine. But problem reappears again after sometime.

Why does this happen ?? How do i maintain the connection without getting disconnected ??

**Edit:- I have tested my application on multiple versions of android devices and it works fine on all other devices except Samsung S6.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth will be disconnected automatically after a fixed period of idle time. You've nothing to do with it if you're using a regular bluetooth peripheral.

To maintain a continuous connection with bluetooth you need to check for idle time in your application and send a garbage data over your `OutputStream` after a fixed period of time. This is not a very good approach though, but works fine to maintain a continuous connection with bluetooth.

You can go for another approach which might freeze your application sometimes, which is creating a rfcommSocket communication each time when the bluetooth gets disconnected. You'll get a disconnection intent when your `BluetoothAdapter` is registered to listen bluetooth communication status. In this approach you need to know the MAC address of your bluetooth device. Here's an example how you would create the rfcommSocket communication:

```
private final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
```

In your `BroadcastReceiver` for Bluetooth intent filters:

```
BluetoothDevice mDevice;
BluetoothSocket bs;

if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
    BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

    if (device.getAddress().equals(YOUR_BT_MAC_ADDRESS)) {
        mDevice = device;
        bs = mDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }

}

if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
    try {
        bs = mDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID); 
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

If this is anything about memory concern, check your `InputStream` and `OutputStream`. Read from `InputStream` until its not cleared.

Comment: This disconnection problem happens only with Samsung S6. I doubt it has to do something with memory. I say this because disconnection happens only after sometime, and doesn't happen once device is restarted.

Comment: "To maintain a continuous connection with bluetooth you need to check for idle time in your application and send a garbage data over your OutputStream after a fixed period of time." To be in constant communication, we continuously send some data(Keep Alive) over the Output Stream. Still problem persists.

Comment: "...creating a rfcommSocket communication each time when the bluetooth gets disconnected." Regarding this, the Bluetooth gets disconnected a number of times, and doing this every-time is not feasible as data load is too much.

Comment: Yes this approach is not very feasible. But keep alive process should work if you can implement it correctly. And, please check if the InputStream is not overflowing.

Comment: Yes, i have implemented the Keep Alive process correctly, and can see the Keep Alive message being sent and acknowledged on both sides.

Comment: "And, please check if the InputStream is not overflowing." I checked the Input Stream, and it is not overflowing. And had the Input Stream been overflowing, i would have got same problem on other mobile phones as well. But i get the issue only on Samsung S6.